# RegisterAssemblyTypes with UsingConstructor

Tags: c#, autofac

I want to register assembly types which has multiple constructors
Autowiring chooses the wrong constructor and want to specify it as I do in RegisterType

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(IController))
    .UsingConstructor(typeof(IUnitOfWork));
```

But when I do this

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IController).Assembly)
    .UsingConstructor(typeof(IUnitOfWork));
```

I get

"No matching constructor exists on type 'System.Object'."

I think this is due to the fact that assembly type is a bit more complex than i thought, but the problem remains open

What should I do?

Comment: Instead of solving this problem in the container configuration, try to solve this by removing the duplicate constructor. You won't be faced with this problem when your service types contain only a single public constructor.

Comment: Naturally this solves the problem, but there's the necessity in current project

Comment: What could be the necessity of having multiple ctors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By doing

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(IController))
       .UsingConstructor(typeof(IUnitOfWork));
```

You register IController inside *Autofac* container and tell it that it should use a constructor with a `IUnitOfWork` parameter.

The `UsingConstructor` method doesn't work with `RegisterAssemblyTypes` but in your case you can use `FindConstructorWith` method.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IController).Assembly)
       .FindConstructorsWith(t => new[] { 
           t.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IUnitOfWork) }) 
       })
       .As<IController>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it'll get the job done, although as I can see FindConstructorWith method introduced only 4 feb 2015, which is way more later than the question. Thankfully, I'm already have single constructor and no longer needed for this crutch